# modify a variable in a anonymous method

Tags: c#, linq-to-objects, anonymous-methods

I want to modify a local variable in a function of extension method.
See

```
int myvar=0;
MyList.Where(
    x =>
        {
            if (condition)
                myvar += 1;
            return false;
        });
return myvar;
```

Why that is not working?

Comment: Why do you think that it isn't working?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You really *don't* want to modify a local variable in the body of a `Where` predicate.  Functions with side-effects like this are bad news; try to imagine what would happen if this comes (for example) from a parallel enumerable generated by `AsParallel()` - you'll have a race condition.

If you explain what you're trying to accomplish, I'm sure that one of us could provide a better means to that end.  My guess is that it would look something like this:

```
int count = myList.Count(x => condition(x));
```

Comment: Now i use .Count() method but my list is very huge and for performance reasons i don't want to use that.

Comment: @Navid: Switching to a method like the one in the question isn't going to improve anything, performance-wise; no matter what, the sequence needs to be iterated entirely and each item evaluated.  The only reason this version runs faster is because `Where` uses deferred execution and in this case is never executed because you never iterate the list.

Comment: @Navid: That depends.  What is your goal?  Where does the data come from?  Why is the list so big?

Comment: In fact i write a program that use evolutionary algorithm to solve a problem. In calculate fitness i use linq to object and this code runs so many that leads to low speed of my program. (i use profiler to know this)

Comment: this is a part of my fitness function :

     fitness +=
             GeneList.Where(
                                x => (x as Gene).Group.Features.Except((x as Gene).Classroom.Features).Count() == 0).Count()
                            * _weights[3];

Comment: @Navid, that's not a whole lot of context, but offhand I can tell you that the `(...).Count() == 0` part is highly inefficient and could be replaced by an `!(...).Any()`.

Answer (score 0):

The `Where` method returns an `IEnumerable<T>` but you haven't actually enumerated it (with foreach, or by manual iteration over the resulting `IEnumerator<T>`).